# Twitter Search API OR operator not working as expected

Tags: r, search, twitter, logical-operators

The results of using R to access the Twitter search API don't seem to follow Boolean logic. Searching for `red AND ball` gets 13,127 hits.

```
tw1 = rtweet::search_tweets('red ball', n = 1e4, retryonratelimit = TRUE)
```

`red AND cat` gets 9,799 hits. `red AND cat AND ball` gets 19 hits. So far so good.

Now, `(red AND cat) OR (red AND ball)` gets only 1 hit. It doesn't matter how I structure it, or whether I use `twitteR` or `rtweet`, so I assume the problem is the search API.

```
tw2 = rtweet::search_tweets('red (ball or cat)', n = 1e4, retryonratelimit = TRUE)
```

or

```
tw3 = rtweet::search_tweets('red ball or cat', n = 1e4, retryonratelimit = TRUE)
```

or

```
tw4 = twitteR::searchTwitter('red ball or cat', n = 1e4, retryOnRateLimit = 1e3)
```

In general, it's amazing to me how poorly documented the Search API is, how glitchy it is, and how few questions have been asked about using it.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How did you come up with `AND` and grouping using parentheses? I'd go with `"red cat OR red ball"`, `"red ball OR red cat"`, and so on. Doc seems to be here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators.html

Comment: Good question, especially given the poor documentation provided by Twitter. This 3rd-party search firm says the syntax is `"a b OR c"` is equivalent to `"a (b OR c)"`, and the latter should be equivalent to both of your formulations. [link](https://unionmetrics.com/resources/how-to-use-advanced-twitter-search-queries/)However, the

Comment: However, the Twitter Developer site [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/guides/using-premium-operators.html) says that for "premium" searches `"a b OR c"` is evaluated as `"(a b) OR c"`, which is very different. Either way, it should not get 1 hit.

Comment: Perhaps more to the point of your Q, the API tends to "break" if standard searches are too long or complex, so I'm trying to use as few terms as possible by taking advantage of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm an idiot and didn't capitalize the OR operator in the code. Running tw2, tw3 or tw4 above with capitalized OR gives the union of `(red AND cat) OR (red AND ball)` as expected.

One useful piece of information I can pass along is that the logical syntax of ORing from the Twitter Developer site linked in the comments does not seem to apply in the free Twitter API. That is, 
    `"a b OR c"` 
is evaluated as 
    `"a (b OR c)"` 
not as 
    `"(a b) OR c"`.